# Page Fault For a Code Fragment

Tags: c++, operating-system

It is not a homework question. It came in my semester exam today.

This code fragment computes the average of each table colum `t[i][j] 0<=i<18 ; 0<=j<1024`

```
for (j = 0; j < 1024; i++) {  
   temp = 0;  
   for (i = 0; i < 18; i++) {  
      temp += temp + t[i][j];  
   }  
   cout << temp/18;
}
```

Variables are 32-bit floating point values.

Variables `i`, `j`, `temp` are stored in processor register(so no need of memory reference to access temp. Main memory is word addressable and paged containing 17 frames, each of size 1024 words and one word is 4 bytes. Page replacement policy is LRU.

**Determine the number of page faults to execute the given program fragment? Ans: 18432**

*How to compute it?*

Comment: @DavidTitarenco, are you asing that every access to array by index generates a page fault?

Comment: @aleguna The inner loop is over the outer index of the array meaning each access is 1024 words apart. Since each frame is 1024 words, there we have it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int array[3][3] = {{0, 1, 2},
                  {3, 4, 5},
                  {6, 7, 8}};
```

The layout of this array in memory is `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` which is

```
array[0][0]
array[0][1]
array[0][2]
array[1][0]
array[1][1]
array[1][2]
array[2][0]
array[2][1]
array[2][2]
```

Here the memory address difference between `array[1][0]` and `array[2][0]` is 3;

So given an array `a[18][1024]`. The difference between `a[i][j]` and `a[i+1][j]` is 1024 bytes(The size of a page fault). So, each time your inner loop triggers that causes a page fault. Your inner loop triggers 18*1024 times(18432).